# How to remove spaces using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

how to remove spaces.
i use onkeyup to show output in div

Thanks

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Title Page</label>
  <input type="text" id="chatinput" class="form-control" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div><b>Permalink: </b>http://doamin.com/<span id="printchatbox" class="cl-blue"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Were you unable to find _any_ information about this?

Comment: `document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value.replace(/\s/g,"");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` to replace spaces with nothing.

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value.replace(' ', '');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Title Page</label>
  <input type="text" id="chatinput" class="form-control" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div><b>Permalink: </b>http://doamin.com/<span id="printchatbox" class="cl-blue"></span></div>
</div>
```

NOTE:

Upon seeing a suggested edit, I must remark that this is **NOT** the correct answer, because it takes care of one space only. If there are multiple spaces in the string, it will remove only the first one. As the editor suggested, the right way to do this is by using a regex. In that case, `replace` would replace all spaces

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Title Page</label>
  <input type="text" id="chatinput" class="form-control" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div><b>Permalink: </b>http://doamin.com/<span id="printchatbox" class="cl-blue"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`

```
  document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value.replace(/\s/g,"");
```

**Demo**

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Title Page</label>
  <input type="text" id="chatinput" class="form-control" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div><b>Permalink: </b>http://doamin.com/<span id="printchatbox" class="cl-blue"></span></div>
</div>
```